# Windows 10: Stereo mix not recording any sound

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, troubleshooting, recording

I was go through a much troubleshooting tutorials about my issue but hasn't fix it.

Setup:

```
Windows 10 2004 19041.572
USB headset: Sades Locus Plus
```

Stereo mix not pick any sound from my USB headset. Also I tried set stereo mix listener to `Virtual Audio Cable Input` device for testing purposes (sound from Google Chrome browser piped to `VAC Output` device correctly [note: that scheme works fine in my OBS setup for background music during the stream]) but stereo mix does not receive any sounds in this case too.

Screenshot of sound playback window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcvET.jpg

Screenshot of sound recording window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/99H61.jpg

Screenshots set of stereo mix setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFhfr.jpg (there on 1 screenshot I note `Realtek(R) Audio` in controller information when my speaker's controller information is `SADES Locust Plus` https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V0nO.jpg and I don't know how to change this)

I have all drivers updated.

How to make stereo mix listener works properly?

**Edit:**

Just tried plug-in my smartphone headphones to 3.5 jack interface on my PC and that's works. But I want to make it works with my USB headset. I don't have 3.5 jack headset for PC.

**Edit 2:**

Accordingly to following reddit reply https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3vh2af/stereo_mix_wont_record_audio/cxnvoe1/ from ~2016

[image]

looks it's not possible. Realtek works only with Realtek compatibility devices while my headset is of Locust manufacturer with own proprietary software.

**Edit 3:**

If there is appears any possible way since 2016 to make things works please help.

**Anyway my main goal is to recording system (OS) audio.**

Comment: You may have to solve it with 3rd party recording software.